# How to concatenate variables in c#

Tags: c#, variables, concatenation

I've been looking around, but haven't seen what i was looking for.
What i try to do is fill radiobuttons desciption with a variable;

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 7; i++)
{
  ctrl = "radiobutton" + i;
  ctrl.Content = "[somevalue]"; // fill each of the radiobuttons descriptions
}
```

Ofcourse this will not work, but how to do this ?

Any help will be appreciated, thanks !

Comment: If you create the radio buttons as an array, you can walk the array and assign the content as you need.

Comment: You should look into databinding your controls instead of creating tons of boilerplate code to assign values to your controls.

Comment: Have you looked at radiobuttonlist with binding?

Comment: I'll go look deeper into the databindings, looks promising. Thanks !!

Answer (score 2):

Easy enough; use `Form.FindControl` ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.mobilecontrols.form.findcontrol(v=vs.110).aspx))

```
Control ctrl = FindControl("radiobutton" + i);
ctrl.Content = "SomeText";
```

Disclaimer: I never said you *should* do this. That design (and naming scheme) is terrible; but this is how you *would* do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign every `radiobutton`'s `Tag` property to some meaningful for you value. 
After pick them from their parent control's `Control` collection based on that values.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all, I came up with this :

```
int items = count / 2;
string[] ctrl= new string[items];
RadioButton [] radioButtons = new RadioButton[items];
for (int i = 0; i < items; i++)
{
    radioButtons[i] = new RadioButton();
    radioButtons[i].Content = EffectsArray[i];
    stackPanelEffRadio.Children.Add(radioButtons[i]);
}
```

Works for me !